# Generate ServiceStack Service from a WSDL

Tags: c#, soap, servicestack

I have been assigned a project where I must integrate with a 3rd party.  The 3rd Party has already built the client and I must build a service that integrates with their client.

I have to create a SOAP Web Service that implements the STAR WS Standards.  It must use WS-Security for the Username/Password.

The 3rd party has given me a WSDL that my Web Service must adhere to.

I have never used ServiceStack before, however, I would like to use ServiceStack for this project.  Is there a way that I can generate a ServiceStack service from the WSDL that I have been given? If so can you please point me in the right direction to get started?

Thanks!

Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong way around.

You don't generate a service from a WSDL, you generate a client gateway from one. [ServiceStack also has a different philosophy to WCF](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack) in that you're encouraged to start with code-first Models then **project out**, so you wouldn't try to reverse engineer services from an existing 3rd Party WSDL, instead you would just develop your services normally and let ServiceStack take care of generating the XSDs/WSDLs for you.

See ServiceStack's [SOAP Support wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) for more info.

Comment: I completely agree that this is the wrong way around.  However, I don't have a choice.  We are integrating with an Industry Giant and we have to do things however they want them to be done or we don't work with them at all.  Both ASMX services and WCF services have the ability to generate a service from the WSDL.  I was hoping that ServiceStack would have the same ability.

Comment: I really don't want to use WCF.  Any advice on how to get starting trying to implement this WSDL with the requirements that I have using ServiceStack? Again, I'm a complete novice to ServiceStack so I need all the help I can get.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy So ServiceStack is a bad choice for **projecting-in**, i.e. trying to reverse-engineer Services from an existing WSDL. If that's what's needed, WCF would be the preferred options. Not that you have any control, but personally I think this approach is going to lead to a world of hurt for any non-trivial implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly unorthodox. As the service provider, it's up to you to define the service contract and up to your consumers to consume it.

Building a client first is all well and good for a tick in the box except that it doesn't bloody work.

Produce your service to spec and then tell the 3rd party to regen their client from it.

Appreciate this doesn't address your query directly.

**EDIT**

The problem you have is that developing a web service from the WSDL is called *contract-first* service development.

Probably the best overview here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx

Unfortunately ServiceStack is strictly a code-first tool, so you can't start with the WSDL and work backwards.

Comment: I understand that it is not the standard way of doing it.  Unfortunately you don't always get to control it.  When you are wanting to work with a 300lb Gorilla you don't get to specify the terms of the integration they do unfortunately.

Comment: If it was up to me I wouldn't be using SOAP in the first place but unfortunately I don't have a say in the matter.

Comment: It's not at all unorthodox. Many B2B APIs require peer services which each end implements so that each may call the other. In that case, one may not be defining the service but still implementing it. One public example I've come across recently is the OCPP specification. http://www.openchargealliance.org/protocols/ocpp/ocpp-15/